# Check the Metastore for the Table availability in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, hive-metastore

I want to check if the table is available in a specific hive database before using the below select query.
How to get the information from the metastore.

```
sparkSession.sql("select * from db_name.table_name")
```

Comment: check this link - https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/demo/demo-connecting-spark-sql-to-hive-metastore.html

Answer (score 1):

you can run below command before run your operation on the table

```
 sparkSession.sql("use databaseName");
 val df = sparkSession.sql("show tables like 'tableName'")
 if(df.head(1).isEmpty == false){
//write the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#This will give the list of tables in the database as a dataframe.
tables = sparkSession.sql('SHOW TABLES IN '+db_name)
#You can collect them to bring in a list of row items
tables_list = tables.select('tableName').collect() 
# convert them into a python array
tables_list_arr=[]
for table_name in tables:
    tables_list_arr.append(str(table_name['tableName']))
# Then execute your command
if(table_name in tables_list_arr):
    sparkSession.sql("select * from db_name.table_name")
```

Comment: Instead of using sparkSession.sql is there is any way to get info using getTableMetadata